# adding multiple executables C-Lion

Tags: c, clion

im pretty new in C-programming. I use CLion from JetBrains to program my stuff. I would like to know how to add multiple c files in the makelist.

i would like to just open a program and to execute it..if its possible

my ide works just for one file. so i always have to change the name of the c. file in the makelist

i have already tried a lot of combinations of the makelists file but nothing worked.

does somebody have an idea how to fix this problem?

[image]

I have edit two new pictures

In this example I have two c files which i would like to execute. 
My goal is to add the whole c file tree on the left side to the CMakeList

Here are the pictures

[!enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwZS0.png)

Here is the error log

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLQE9.png)

Here is the solution. Thanks to your response someprogramerdude

I just added executables and i changed the project in the beginning. the reason why i use picture is that you can see the source files on the left side

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZb7P.png)

Comment: You have highlighted *one* source file that will be added when creating the executable. How do you think you add other files?

Comment: And what makes you think you can only have one `add_executable`? Have you *tried* adding another?

Comment: It is not clear whether you are talking about a single program comprising of multiple source files, or  single _project_ with multiple executable targets (separate programs).   If the latter, you need to create a separate project  for each program perhaps.

Comment: Please don't post images of text, copy-paste the actual text as text instead. Please [learn how to format text properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: And your problem seems to be that you have multiple *different* programs. Each program needs to be built into a separate executable. You can do that by adding more `add_executable` commands in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, adding only the source files needed for that specific executable.

Comment: My goal is to have multiple source files in one project. I have tried to add a new line with an executable but it didnt help.